# Oracle package - Return select into table of %rowtype - too many values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I´m trying to return data having the field "Kasser" containing multiple rows. I have beed reading about %rowtype, varray, select into, fetch, BULK COLLECT - but this problem I can´t crack.

From the Package Specs:

```
type kasse_records is table of YY_network%rowtype;

type det_branch_dep_data_record is record(
  WEBID               XY_FILIALER.webid%type,
  LATITUDE            xy_geolokation.latitude%type,
  LONGITUDE           xy_geolokation.longitude%type,
  KASSER              kasse_records
);

type branchdepartment_cur is ref cursor
  return det_branch_dep_data_record;

procedure getbranchdepartment(
   branchdepartmentout out branchdepartment_cur 
);
```

From the package:

```
procedure getbranchdepartment(branchdepartmentout out branchdepartment_cur)

    is

    begin
        open branchdepartmentout for
        SELECT 
         WEBID,
         ga.latitude,
         ga.longitude,
            (
            select net.*
                from YY_network net
                join xal_enumvalues on net.networktype = xal_enumvalues.valuenum
                and xal_enumvalues.enumnum = 271
                and xal_enumvalues.valuenum = 1
                and NET.NETWORKTYPE = 1 
                and PORT != chr(2)
                where net.filialid = fl.filialid
            ) kasser
        FROM XY_FILIALER fl
            INNER JOIN TOOLS.XAL_ENUMVALUES BK ON (BUTIKSKXDE = VALUENUM)
            left join xy_geolokation ga on ga.dataset = fl.dataset 
            and ga.reffileid = 757 
            and ga.refrecid = fl.lxbenummer 
        WHERE (ENUMNUM = 267) AND (AKTIV = 1)
        and fl.dataset = 'DAT'
        and fl.filialid != 'CENTRAL'
        ORDER BY BUTIKSKXDE, fl.Navn;
    end getbranchdepartment;
```

Comment: Can you post your select into part as well.

Comment: I don't think you can define a SQL type with %ROWTYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it should be like this one:

```
OPEN branchdepartmentout FOR
SELECT 
    WEBID,
    ga.latitude,
    ga.longitude,
    CAST(MULTISET(
        SELECT net.*
        FROM YY_network net
            JOIN xal_enumvalues ON net.networktype = xal_enumvalues.valuenum
            AND xal_enumvalues.enumnum = 271
            AND xal_enumvalues.valuenum = 1
            AND NET.NETWORKTYPE = 1 
            AND PORT != CHR(2)
        WHERE net.filialid = fl.filialid
    ) AS kasse_records) AS kasser 
FROM XY_FILIALER fl
    INNER JOIN TOOLS.XAL_ENUMVALUES BK ON (BUTIKSKXDE = VALUENUM)
    LEFT JOIN xy_geolokation ga ON ga.dataset = fl.dataset 
        AND ga.reffileid = 757 
        AND ga.refrecid = fl.lxbenummer 
WHERE (ENUMNUM = 267) AND (AKTIV = 1)
    AND fl.dataset = 'DAT'
    AND fl.filialid != 'CENTRAL'
ORDER BY BUTIKSKXDE, fl.Navn;
```

However, you cannot make `CAST(MULTISET(SELECT ...) AS kasse_records)` when `kasse_records` is a locally defined type, it must be a schema type, i.e. you must create it beforehand by `CREATE TYPE kasse_records AS TABLE OF ...`

But schema object must not based on `%ROWTYPE` attributes, hence you have to create `kasse_record` manually.

So something like:

```
create type kasse_record as OBJECT (
  networktype NUMBER,
  filialid NUMBER,
  port INTEGER,
  ...
);

create type kasse_records as table of kasse_record;

create type det_branch_dep_data_record is record(
  WEBID               XY_FILIALER.webid%type,
  LATITUDE            xy_geolokation.latitude%type,
  LONGITUDE           xy_geolokation.longitude%type,
  KASSER              kasse_records
);
```

Then the query should be:

```
OPEN branchdepartmentout FOR
SELECT 
    WEBID,
    ga.latitude,
    ga.longitude,
    CAST(MULTISET(
        SELECT kasse_record(net.networktype, net.filialid, net.port, ...)
        FROM YY_network net
            JOIN xal_enumvalues ON net.networktype = xal_enumvalues.valuenum
            AND xal_enumvalues.enumnum = 271
            AND xal_enumvalues.valuenum = 1
            AND NET.NETWORKTYPE = 1 
            AND PORT != CHR(2)
        WHERE net.filialid = fl.filialid
    ) AS kasse_records) AS kasser 
FROM XY_FILIALER fl
...
```

Comment: First an "Invalid datatype error", then i changed to 
AS SUPERVISOR.XH_SP_DEPARTMENTS_WRK.KASSE_RECORDS) as kasser
Now I get an "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" - but all paranthesis are closed...

Comment: Take error "missing right parenthesis" seriously and check your query again.

Comment: Thanks It´s working now. I kept the det_branch_dep_data_record in the specs, and made type kasse_records and type kasse_record as schema types.